# Rails 3 - add dynamic nested attributes without nested form gem

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

---

Hello people

In my rails app I'm trying to add nested attributes dynamically, but I don't want to use "nested form gem"

So I found this example https://github.com/alloy/complex-form-examples/blob/a234fde4419836f277d7e340657f1d8418911d68/app/helpers/projects_helper.rb  but this code doesn't work

```
module ProjectsHelper
  def remove_link_unless_new_record(fields)
    unless fields.object.new_record?
      out = ''
      out << fields.hidden_field(:_delete)
      out << link_to_function("remove", "$(this).up('.#{fields.object.class.name.underscore}').hide(); $(this).previous().value = '1'")
      out
    end
  end
end
```

I think that lines  which starts with "out <<" make some conflicts, because I've checked the html (firebug) and the simbols "<" and ">" doesn't appear

```
&lt;a href="#" onclick="$(this).up('.task').hide(); $(this).previous().value = '1'; return false;"&gt;remove&lt;/a&gt;
```

Can you help me please??  Thanks

Comment: Why dont you want to use the nested form gem?

Comment: Because some jquery functions are not working when I call them inside a nested form, so I'm looking for another way to add nested attributes and be able to use jquery functions with them